# Ajax return html and use jquery on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: 'http://www.mytestsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  data:{
       'action':'display_image',
       'id_page': 9
       },
  success:function(data){
    $('#ajax').html(data);
  }
});
```

It works perfectly my div ID "ajax" display the html code:

```
<span id="test">HELLO</span>
```

The problem is in my footer page i have:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
alert('test');
});
```

When i click on "HELLO" (the html return of my ajax call) an alert box will display but it doesnt work. I dont know why...

Comment: You need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically loaded elements. `$("#ajax").on("click", "#test", function () { alert("test"); });`

Comment: Is this span is the part of HTML loaded by ajax?

Comment: the content is dynamically added, so when you set the listener, the content didn't exist so no handler got added

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the clickevent after you show the resulting htmlcode on the page. So just put the on-function inside your success function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the content is loaded dynamically, you have two options:

1. You can bind the click event to an ancestor element that isn't dynamically loaded; so that when it is clicked, it searches for your selector and then calls the function:

   ```
   $('body').on('click','#test', function(){
      alert('test');
   });
   ```
2. After your content is loaded, you can bind a new event to that content.  This would need to occur in your AJAX success callback (or some sort of promise).  This would be a little more involved, since you said the code was in your footer page.

Comment: You know better than to answer duplicate questions

Comment: @mhodges I didn't realize it was a duplicate, I'm just scanning the questions before lunch ;)